# solution for a homework in racket

Tags: racket

i'm new to racket Programming language.
i need to provide a solution in racket but i couldn't write something that works.

question :

Define a max-gap function that consumes five integers and returns the largest gap (in absolute value, i.e., a natural number) within any two (in the order in which they appear). For example, (max-gap 1 3 -1 1 1) would return 4. You might want to use the Racket functions max, abs.

output for example:

(test (max-gap 1 5 -1 6 22) => 16)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Show what didn't work. Then someone might help you, were you got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#lang racket
(require datalog)

(define mg-theory (make-theory))
(datalog mg-theory
         (! (:- (max-gap-datalog A B C D E X)
                (max A B C D E :- MX)
                (min A B C D E :- MN)
                (- MX MN :- X))))
(define (max-gap a b c d e)
  (hash-ref (first
             (datalog mg-theory
                      (? (max-gap-datalog a b c d e X)))) 'X))
```

Example:

```
> (max-gap 1 3 -1 1 1)
4
> (max-gap 1 5 -1 6 22)
23
```

If you post some of the attempts you've made, I will help you arrive at a more idiomatic solution than this one.

Comment: well that's just great but i found that i mislead by forgot to mention that i forced to use an add-on to the language which called PL. other than that, the solution is made only for 5 numbers. in my homework we required to make a solution for X numbers.

Comment: We can't help you if you keep moving the goalposts.